# Read percentile data Pxx(a,b)

Tags: math, percentile

Here is the data

```
P0(24,0) P25(32.1875,26.6735) P50(35.4167,31.383) P75(40.45,42.6203) 
P90(50.55,59.1531) P95(53.05,77.3846) P99(60.21,128.643) 
P99.5(60.605,236.321) P99.9(60.921,5854.43) P100(61,63000)
```

I know P0 means 0th percentile and so on. What are the values in the brackets

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two variables, a and b.

The first entry corresponds to a and the second entry corresponds to b.

`P25(32.1875,26.6735)` means `32.1875` is the 25th percentile of a and `26.6735` is the 25th percentile of b.